# Why my docker container is never starting up?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm, wsgi

I have following docker compose file:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:11
        volumes:
            - myapp_postgres_volume:/var/lib/postgresql/data
            - type: tmpfs
              target: /dev/shm
              tmpfs:
                size: 536870912 # 512MB
        environment:
            POSTGRES_DB: elearning_academy
            POSTGRES_USER: myapp
            POSTGRES_PASSWORD: myapp123
        networks:
            - myapp_network

    redis:
        image: redis:6.2.4
        volumes:
            - myapp_redis_volume:/data
        networks:
            - myapp_network

    wsgi:
        image: wsgi:myapp3_stack2
        volumes:
            - /myapp/frontend/static/
            - ./wsgi/myapp:/myapp
            - /myapp/frontend/clientApp/node_modules
            - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
            - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
        depends_on:
            - postgres
            - redis
        ports:
            - 9090
            #- 8000:8000
        environment:
            C_FORCE_ROOT: 'true'
            SERVICE_PORTS: 9090
        networks:
            - myapp_network
        deploy:
            replicas: 1
            update_config:
                parallelism: 1
                delay: 10s
            restart_policy:
                condition: on-failure
                max_attempts: 3
                window: 120s

    nodejs:
        image: nodejs:myapp3_stack2
        volumes:
            - ./nodejs/frontend:/frontend
            - /frontend/node_modules
        depends_on:
            - wsgi
        ports:
            - 9000:9000 # development
            - 9999:9999 # production
        environment:
            BACKEND_API_URL: http://0.0.0.0:9763/api/
        networks:
            - myapp_network

    nginx:
        image: nginx-brotli:1.21.0
        volumes:
            - ./nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
            - ./wsgi/myapp:/myapp:ro
            - myapp_nginx_volume:/var/log/nginx/
            - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
            - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
        networks:
            - myapp_network
            
    haproxy:
        image: haproxy:2.3.9
        volumes:
            - ./haproxy:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/:ro
            - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
            - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
            - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
        depends_on:
            - wsgi
            - nodejs
            - nginx
        ports:
            - 9763:80
        networks:
            - myapp_network
        deploy:
            placement:
                constraints: [node.role == manager]

volumes:
    myapp_postgres_volume:
    myapp_redis_volume:
    myapp_nginx_volume:

networks:
    myapp_network:
        driver: overlay
```

I have following configs in haproxy.cfg:

```
backend http
    balance roundrobin
    server nodejs nodejs:9999 check

backend api
    balance roundrobin
    server wsgi wsgi:9090 check
```

When I run `docker compose deploy -c docker-compose.yml myapp_stack_2`, it only starts containers for nginx, postgres and redis. Following is the output of `watch n -2 docker container ls`:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                  PORTS      NAMES
746df4cfeb87   haproxy:2.3.9                  "docker-entrypoint.s…"   5 seconds ago    Up Less than a second              myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.foz4xytdcecwbht84dc0q1emh
72cc2059806c   redis:6.2.4                    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   13 seconds ago   Up 12 seconds           6379/tcp   myapp_stack_2_redis.1.39plxmr0kw6h68fjjlcg1alrg
e11d221ffbae   postgres:11                    "docker-entrypoint.s…"   17 seconds ago   Up 16 seconds           5432/tcp   myapp_stack_2_postgres.1.legyfu6kgd2dfnumgfbrze73k
afd0740094b4   nginx-brotli:1.21.0   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   23 seconds ago   Up 23 seconds           80/tcp     myapp_stack_2_nginx.1.me1bdetze9ed50ojl9x2u9t93
```

The `haproxy` containers keeps appearing and disappearing from the list, never remaining stable forever. I checked the logs for haproxy container and this is what it has:

```
[NOTICE] 141/064759 (1) : haproxy version is 2.3.9-53945bf
[NOTICE] 141/064759 (1) : path to executable is /usr/local/sbin/haproxy
[ALERT] 141/064759 (1) : parsing [/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:43] : 'server nodejs' : could not resolve address 'nodejs'.
[ALERT] 141/064759 (1) : parsing [/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:47] : 'server wsgi' : could not resolve address 'wsgi'.
[ALERT] 141/064759 (1) : parsing [/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg:52] : 'server wsgi' : could not resolve address 'wsgi'.
[ALERT] 141/064759 (1) : Failed to initialize server(s) addr.
 *  Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
```

So from haproxy logs, it seems that `haproxy` fails to start because `wsgi` container is not starting up. Also `nodejs` container is not starting up because it depends on `wsgi` container. Now I am guessing why `wsgi` container is not starting up? `haproxy` container appears at least momentarily in the `docker container ls` command output. But `wsgi` container never appears even in `docker container ls -a` command output. It neither appears in the `docker events` output. Below is my `docker events` command output:

```
network create 9yo7n7g7uybtbasehwly0a21p (name=myapp_stack_2_myapp_network, type=overlay)
volume create myapp_stack_2_myapp_nginx_volume (driver=local)
container create acf160662847238e45c91e4412b4669fe964618514f295279268686995ae564e (com.docker.stack.namespace=myapp_stack_2, com.docker.swarm.node.id=txx4ub7iz1naiytqjnaefyaus, com.docker.swarm.service.id=dl5hg45n5t8z95sufecfyv3mm, com.docker.swarm.service.name=myapp_stack_2_nginx, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=20mvcffi41gefsmo2gyz5rmmh, com.docker.swarm.task.name=myapp_stack_2_nginx.1.20mvcffi41gefsmo2gyz5rmmh, image=ishtiyaq/nginx-brotli:1.21.0@sha256:436cbc0d8cd051e7bdb197d7915fe90fa5a1bdadea6d02272ba117fccf30c936, maintainer=NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>, name=myapp_stack_2_nginx.1.20mvcffi41gefsmo2gyz5rmmh)
network connect 9yo7n7g7uybtbasehwly0a21p (container=acf160662847238e45c91e4412b4669fe964618514f295279268686995ae564e, name=myapp_stack_2_myapp_network, type=overlay)
volume mount myapp_stack_2_myapp_nginx_volume (container=acf160662847238e45c91e4412b4669fe964618514f295279268686995ae564e, destination=/var/log/nginx, driver=local, propagation=, read/write=true)
container start acf160662847238e45c91e4412b4669fe964618514f295279268686995ae564e (com.docker.stack.namespace=myapp_stack_2, com.docker.swarm.node.id=txx4ub7iz1naiytqjnaefyaus, com.docker.swarm.service.id=dl5hg45n5t8z95sufecfyv3mm, com.docker.swarm.service.name=myapp_stack_2_nginx, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=20mvcffi41gefsmo2gyz5rmmh, com.docker.swarm.task.name=myapp_stack_2_nginx.1.20mvcffi41gefsmo2gyz5rmmh, image=ishtiyaq/nginx-brotli:1.21.0@sha256:436cbc0d8cd051e7bdb197d7915fe90fa5a1bdadea6d02272ba117fccf30c936, maintainer=NGINX Docker Maintainers <docker-maint@nginx.com>, name=myapp_stack_2_nginx.1.20mvcffi41gefsmo2gyz5rmmh)
container create 9ba52fa387f4b33690989a588207075bf5988b8f376aeea913e6d9f95293b88c (com.docker.stack.namespace=myapp_stack_2, com.docker.swarm.node.id=txx4ub7iz1naiytqjnaefyaus, com.docker.swarm.service.id=oijtd9i6abt9bftjgit1ftoy7, com.docker.swarm.service.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=nj02e0g8gvbntnnxdjt3o7h07, com.docker.swarm.task.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.nj02e0g8gvbntnnxdjt3o7h07, image=haproxy:2.3.9@sha256:f63aabf39efcd277b04a503d38e59e80224a0c11f47b2568b13b0092698c5a3a, name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.nj02e0g8gvbntnnxdjt3o7h07)
network connect rywtwie2qb45ar6vjsjm7uqn9 (container=9ba52fa387f4b33690989a588207075bf5988b8f376aeea913e6d9f95293b88c, name=ingress, type=overlay)
network connect 9yo7n7g7uybtbasehwly0a21p (container=9ba52fa387f4b33690989a588207075bf5988b8f376aeea913e6d9f95293b88c, name=myapp_stack_2_myapp_network, type=overlay)
container start 9ba52fa387f4b33690989a588207075bf5988b8f376aeea913e6d9f95293b88c (com.docker.stack.namespace=myapp_stack_2, com.docker.swarm.node.id=txx4ub7iz1naiytqjnaefyaus, com.docker.swarm.service.id=oijtd9i6abt9bftjgit1ftoy7, com.docker.swarm.service.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=nj02e0g8gvbntnnxdjt3o7h07, com.docker.swarm.task.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.nj02e0g8gvbntnnxdjt3o7h07, image=haproxy:2.3.9@sha256:f63aabf39efcd277b04a503d38e59e80224a0c11f47b2568b13b0092698c5a3a, name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.nj02e0g8gvbntnnxdjt3o7h07)
container die 9ba52fa387f4b33690989a588207075bf5988b8f376aeea913e6d9f95293b88c (com.docker.stack.namespace=myapp_stack_2, com.docker.swarm.node.id=txx4ub7iz1naiytqjnaefyaus, com.docker.swarm.service.id=oijtd9i6abt9bftjgit1ftoy7, com.docker.swarm.service.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=nj02e0g8gvbntnnxdjt3o7h07, com.docker.swarm.task.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.nj02e0g8gvbntnnxdjt3o7h07, exitCode=1, image=haproxy:2.3.9@sha256:f63aabf39efcd277b04a503d38e59e80224a0c11f47b2568b13b0092698c5a3a, name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.nj02e0g8gvbntnnxdjt3o7h07)
network disconnect rywtwie2qb45ar6vjsjm7uqn9 (container=9ba52fa387f4b33690989a588207075bf5988b8f376aeea913e6d9f95293b88c, name=ingress, type=overlay)
network disconnect 9yo7n7g7uybtbasehwly0a21p (container=9ba52fa387f4b33690989a588207075bf5988b8f376aeea913e6d9f95293b88c, name=myapp_stack_2_myapp_network, type=overlay)
container create 32350a97913ad26fabc0f595d078e83c4d6e1a4379cad4aa82160e7707c5cd31 (com.docker.stack.namespace=myapp_stack_2, com.docker.swarm.node.id=txx4ub7iz1naiytqjnaefyaus, com.docker.swarm.service.id=oijtd9i6abt9bftjgit1ftoy7, com.docker.swarm.service.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=idbnqytqsl9pxgvha8jn3um7l, com.docker.swarm.task.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.idbnqytqsl9pxgvha8jn3um7l, image=haproxy:2.3.9@sha256:f63aabf39efcd277b04a503d38e59e80224a0c11f47b2568b13b0092698c5a3a, name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.idbnqytqsl9pxgvha8jn3um7l)
volume create myapp_stack_2_myapp_postgres_volume (driver=local)
container create cb285ae8b5c9dd38b04ea4630342467dc3686776951ec2715812ad02bb7d0e71 (com.docker.stack.namespace=myapp_stack_2, com.docker.swarm.node.id=txx4ub7iz1naiytqjnaefyaus, com.docker.swarm.service.id=3u8k5u7rw58v0tj2kgfr2v8i2, com.docker.swarm.service.name=myapp_stack_2_postgres, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=m087yyeluafrmcdzmgnoyv3e6, com.docker.swarm.task.name=myapp_stack_2_postgres.1.m087yyeluafrmcdzmgnoyv3e6, image=postgres:11@sha256:5d2aa4a7b5f9bdadeddcf87cf7f90a176737a02a30d917de4ab2e6a329bd2d45, name=myapp_stack_2_postgres.1.m087yyeluafrmcdzmgnoyv3e6)
network connect 9yo7n7g7uybtbasehwly0a21p (container=cb285ae8b5c9dd38b04ea4630342467dc3686776951ec2715812ad02bb7d0e71, name=myapp_stack_2_myapp_network, type=overlay)
volume mount myapp_stack_2_myapp_postgres_volume (container=cb285ae8b5c9dd38b04ea4630342467dc3686776951ec2715812ad02bb7d0e71, destination=/var/lib/postgresql/data, driver=local, propagation=, read/write=true)
container start cb285ae8b5c9dd38b04ea4630342467dc3686776951ec2715812ad02bb7d0e71 (com.docker.stack.namespace=myapp_stack_2, com.docker.swarm.node.id=txx4ub7iz1naiytqjnaefyaus, com.docker.swarm.service.id=3u8k5u7rw58v0tj2kgfr2v8i2, com.docker.swarm.service.name=myapp_stack_2_postgres, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=m087yyeluafrmcdzmgnoyv3e6, com.docker.swarm.task.name=myapp_stack_2_postgres.1.m087yyeluafrmcdzmgnoyv3e6, image=postgres:11@sha256:5d2aa4a7b5f9bdadeddcf87cf7f90a176737a02a30d917de4ab2e6a329bd2d45, name=myapp_stack_2_postgres.1.m087yyeluafrmcdzmgnoyv3e6)
network connect rywtwie2qb45ar6vjsjm7uqn9 (container=32350a97913ad26fabc0f595d078e83c4d6e1a4379cad4aa82160e7707c5cd31, name=ingress, type=overlay)
network connect 9yo7n7g7uybtbasehwly0a21p (container=32350a97913ad26fabc0f595d078e83c4d6e1a4379cad4aa82160e7707c5cd31, name=myapp_stack_2_myapp_network, type=overlay)
volume create myapp_stack_2_myapp_redis_volume (driver=local)
container create 6b485084b77506ab38585f68a4c9f4090002ec338cb46176d86b154b9bff2a34 (com.docker.stack.namespace=myapp_stack_2, com.docker.swarm.node.id=txx4ub7iz1naiytqjnaefyaus, com.docker.swarm.service.id=vqftmbm6sam07emcl590f2dv5, com.docker.swarm.service.name=myapp_stack_2_redis, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=n34chfhozhk082tip6oplxq6d, com.docker.swarm.task.name=myapp_stack_2_redis.1.n34chfhozhk082tip6oplxq6d, image=redis:6.2.4@sha256:6bc98f513258e0c17bd150a7a26f38a8ce3e7d584f0c451cf31df70d461a200a, name=myapp_stack_2_redis.1.n34chfhozhk082tip6oplxq6d)
network connect 9yo7n7g7uybtbasehwly0a21p (container=6b485084b77506ab38585f68a4c9f4090002ec338cb46176d86b154b9bff2a34, name=myapp_stack_2_myapp_network, type=overlay)
volume mount myapp_stack_2_myapp_redis_volume (container=6b485084b77506ab38585f68a4c9f4090002ec338cb46176d86b154b9bff2a34, destination=/data, driver=local, propagation=, read/write=true)
container start 32350a97913ad26fabc0f595d078e83c4d6e1a4379cad4aa82160e7707c5cd31 (com.docker.stack.namespace=myapp_stack_2, com.docker.swarm.node.id=txx4ub7iz1naiytqjnaefyaus, com.docker.swarm.service.id=oijtd9i6abt9bftjgit1ftoy7, com.docker.swarm.service.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=idbnqytqsl9pxgvha8jn3um7l, com.docker.swarm.task.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.idbnqytqsl9pxgvha8jn3um7l, image=haproxy:2.3.9@sha256:f63aabf39efcd277b04a503d38e59e80224a0c11f47b2568b13b0092698c5a3a, name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.idbnqytqsl9pxgvha8jn3um7l)
container die 32350a97913ad26fabc0f595d078e83c4d6e1a4379cad4aa82160e7707c5cd31 (com.docker.stack.namespace=myapp_stack_2, com.docker.swarm.node.id=txx4ub7iz1naiytqjnaefyaus, com.docker.swarm.service.id=oijtd9i6abt9bftjgit1ftoy7, com.docker.swarm.service.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=idbnqytqsl9pxgvha8jn3um7l, com.docker.swarm.task.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.idbnqytqsl9pxgvha8jn3um7l, exitCode=1, image=haproxy:2.3.9@sha256:f63aabf39efcd277b04a503d38e59e80224a0c11f47b2568b13b0092698c5a3a, name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.idbnqytqsl9pxgvha8jn3um7l)
container start 6b485084b77506ab38585f68a4c9f4090002ec338cb46176d86b154b9bff2a34 (com.docker.stack.namespace=myapp_stack_2, com.docker.swarm.node.id=txx4ub7iz1naiytqjnaefyaus, com.docker.swarm.service.id=vqftmbm6sam07emcl590f2dv5, com.docker.swarm.service.name=myapp_stack_2_redis, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=n34chfhozhk082tip6oplxq6d, com.docker.swarm.task.name=myapp_stack_2_redis.1.n34chfhozhk082tip6oplxq6d, image=redis:6.2.4@sha256:6bc98f513258e0c17bd150a7a26f38a8ce3e7d584f0c451cf31df70d461a200a, name=myapp_stack_2_redis.1.n34chfhozhk082tip6oplxq6d)
network disconnect rywtwie2qb45ar6vjsjm7uqn9 (container=32350a97913ad26fabc0f595d078e83c4d6e1a4379cad4aa82160e7707c5cd31, name=ingress, type=overlay)
network disconnect 9yo7n7g7uybtbasehwly0a21p (container=32350a97913ad26fabc0f595d078e83c4d6e1a4379cad4aa82160e7707c5cd31, name=myapp_stack_2_myapp_network, type=overlay)
container create 096c54edca76c5a28df70facca078858e9cdee6ada55f4c372c6a2540ee3bb46 (com.docker.stack.namespace=myapp_stack_2, com.docker.swarm.node.id=txx4ub7iz1naiytqjnaefyaus, com.docker.swarm.service.id=oijtd9i6abt9bftjgit1ftoy7, com.docker.swarm.service.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=hx8lv7lvk6hqn4d11hft0wcl3, com.docker.swarm.task.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.hx8lv7lvk6hqn4d11hft0wcl3, image=haproxy:2.3.9@sha256:f63aabf39efcd277b04a503d38e59e80224a0c11f47b2568b13b0092698c5a3a, name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.hx8lv7lvk6hqn4d11hft0wcl3)
network connect rywtwie2qb45ar6vjsjm7uqn9 (container=096c54edca76c5a28df70facca078858e9cdee6ada55f4c372c6a2540ee3bb46, name=ingress, type=overlay)
network connect 9yo7n7g7uybtbasehwly0a21p (container=096c54edca76c5a28df70facca078858e9cdee6ada55f4c372c6a2540ee3bb46, name=myapp_stack_2_myapp_network, type=overlay)
container start 096c54edca76c5a28df70facca078858e9cdee6ada55f4c372c6a2540ee3bb46 (com.docker.stack.namespace=myapp_stack_2, com.docker.swarm.node.id=txx4ub7iz1naiytqjnaefyaus, com.docker.swarm.service.id=oijtd9i6abt9bftjgit1ftoy7, com.docker.swarm.service.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=hx8lv7lvk6hqn4d11hft0wcl3, com.docker.swarm.task.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.hx8lv7lvk6hqn4d11hft0wcl3, image=haproxy:2.3.9@sha256:f63aabf39efcd277b04a503d38e59e80224a0c11f47b2568b13b0092698c5a3a, name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.hx8lv7lvk6hqn4d11hft0wcl3)
container die 096c54edca76c5a28df70facca078858e9cdee6ada55f4c372c6a2540ee3bb46 (com.docker.stack.namespace=myapp_stack_2, com.docker.swarm.node.id=txx4ub7iz1naiytqjnaefyaus, com.docker.swarm.service.id=oijtd9i6abt9bftjgit1ftoy7, com.docker.swarm.service.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=hx8lv7lvk6hqn4d11hft0wcl3, com.docker.swarm.task.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.hx8lv7lvk6hqn4d11hft0wcl3, exitCode=1, image=haproxy:2.3.9@sha256:f63aabf39efcd277b04a503d38e59e80224a0c11f47b2568b13b0092698c5a3a, name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.hx8lv7lvk6hqn4d11hft0wcl3)
network disconnect rywtwie2qb45ar6vjsjm7uqn9 (container=096c54edca76c5a28df70facca078858e9cdee6ada55f4c372c6a2540ee3bb46, name=ingress, type=overlay)
network disconnect 9yo7n7g7uybtbasehwly0a21p (container=096c54edca76c5a28df70facca078858e9cdee6ada55f4c372c6a2540ee3bb46, name=myapp_stack_2_myapp_network, type=overlay)
container create 603f73ec69bd94be9b62248e91523d5b8ed1425975a157e09b80818367c09f03 (com.docker.stack.namespace=myapp_stack_2, com.docker.swarm.node.id=txx4ub7iz1naiytqjnaefyaus, com.docker.swarm.service.id=oijtd9i6abt9bftjgit1ftoy7, com.docker.swarm.service.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=qo8nr8d68nx8f1pi2chv8lm3z, com.docker.swarm.task.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.qo8nr8d68nx8f1pi2chv8lm3z, image=haproxy:2.3.9@sha256:f63aabf39efcd277b04a503d38e59e80224a0c11f47b2568b13b0092698c5a3a, name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.qo8nr8d68nx8f1pi2chv8lm3z)
network connect rywtwie2qb45ar6vjsjm7uqn9 (container=603f73ec69bd94be9b62248e91523d5b8ed1425975a157e09b80818367c09f03, name=ingress, type=overlay)
network connect 9yo7n7g7uybtbasehwly0a21p (container=603f73ec69bd94be9b62248e91523d5b8ed1425975a157e09b80818367c09f03, name=myapp_stack_2_myapp_network, type=overlay)
container start 603f73ec69bd94be9b62248e91523d5b8ed1425975a157e09b80818367c09f03 (com.docker.stack.namespace=myapp_stack_2, com.docker.swarm.node.id=txx4ub7iz1naiytqjnaefyaus, com.docker.swarm.service.id=oijtd9i6abt9bftjgit1ftoy7, com.docker.swarm.service.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=qo8nr8d68nx8f1pi2chv8lm3z, com.docker.swarm.task.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.qo8nr8d68nx8f1pi2chv8lm3z, image=haproxy:2.3.9@sha256:f63aabf39efcd277b04a503d38e59e80224a0c11f47b2568b13b0092698c5a3a, name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.qo8nr8d68nx8f1pi2chv8lm3z)
container die 603f73ec69bd94be9b62248e91523d5b8ed1425975a157e09b80818367c09f03 (com.docker.stack.namespace=myapp_stack_2, com.docker.swarm.node.id=txx4ub7iz1naiytqjnaefyaus, com.docker.swarm.service.id=oijtd9i6abt9bftjgit1ftoy7, com.docker.swarm.service.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=qo8nr8d68nx8f1pi2chv8lm3z, com.docker.swarm.task.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.qo8nr8d68nx8f1pi2chv8lm3z, exitCode=1, image=haproxy:2.3.9@sha256:f63aabf39efcd277b04a503d38e59e80224a0c11f47b2568b13b0092698c5a3a, name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.qo8nr8d68nx8f1pi2chv8lm3z)
network disconnect rywtwie2qb45ar6vjsjm7uqn9 (container=603f73ec69bd94be9b62248e91523d5b8ed1425975a157e09b80818367c09f03, name=ingress, type=overlay)
network disconnect 9yo7n7g7uybtbasehwly0a21p (container=603f73ec69bd94be9b62248e91523d5b8ed1425975a157e09b80818367c09f03, name=myapp_stack_2_myapp_network, type=overlay)
container create 358a0661c03686b49eb1a960b9a290fd18821c99422b1f3d3211e47b6a83e26c (com.docker.stack.namespace=myapp_stack_2, com.docker.swarm.node.id=txx4ub7iz1naiytqjnaefyaus, com.docker.swarm.service.id=oijtd9i6abt9bftjgit1ftoy7, com.docker.swarm.service.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=ztr1v8y2gheyc30hfes26ii2i, com.docker.swarm.task.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.ztr1v8y2gheyc30hfes26ii2i, image=haproxy:2.3.9@sha256:f63aabf39efcd277b04a503d38e59e80224a0c11f47b2568b13b0092698c5a3a, name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.ztr1v8y2gheyc30hfes26ii2i)
network connect 9yo7n7g7uybtbasehwly0a21p (container=358a0661c03686b49eb1a960b9a290fd18821c99422b1f3d3211e47b6a83e26c, name=myapp_stack_2_myapp_network, type=overlay)
network connect rywtwie2qb45ar6vjsjm7uqn9 (container=358a0661c03686b49eb1a960b9a290fd18821c99422b1f3d3211e47b6a83e26c, name=ingress, type=overlay)
container start 358a0661c03686b49eb1a960b9a290fd18821c99422b1f3d3211e47b6a83e26c (com.docker.stack.namespace=myapp_stack_2, com.docker.swarm.node.id=txx4ub7iz1naiytqjnaefyaus, com.docker.swarm.service.id=oijtd9i6abt9bftjgit1ftoy7, com.docker.swarm.service.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=ztr1v8y2gheyc30hfes26ii2i, com.docker.swarm.task.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.ztr1v8y2gheyc30hfes26ii2i, image=haproxy:2.3.9@sha256:f63aabf39efcd277b04a503d38e59e80224a0c11f47b2568b13b0092698c5a3a, name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.ztr1v8y2gheyc30hfes26ii2i)
container die 358a0661c03686b49eb1a960b9a290fd18821c99422b1f3d3211e47b6a83e26c (com.docker.stack.namespace=myapp_stack_2, com.docker.swarm.node.id=txx4ub7iz1naiytqjnaefyaus, com.docker.swarm.service.id=oijtd9i6abt9bftjgit1ftoy7, com.docker.swarm.service.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy, com.docker.swarm.task=, com.docker.swarm.task.id=ztr1v8y2gheyc30hfes26ii2i, com.docker.swarm.task.name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.ztr1v8y2gheyc30hfes26ii2i, exitCode=1, image=haproxy:2.3.9@sha256:f63aabf39efcd277b04a503d38e59e80224a0c11f47b2568b13b0092698c5a3a, name=myapp_stack_2_haproxy.1.ztr1v8y2gheyc30hfes26ii2i)
network disconnect rywtwie2qb45ar6vjsjm7uqn9 (container=358a0661c03686b49eb1a960b9a290fd18821c99422b1f3d3211e47b6a83e26c, name=ingress, type=overlay)
network disconnect 9yo7n7g7uybtbasehwly0a21p (container=358a0661c03686b49eb1a960b9a290fd18821c99422b1f3d3211e47b6a83e26c, name=myapp_stack_2_myapp_network, type=overlay
```

So am not able to get logs of `wsgi` container logs and find out why its never started. How can I know why `wsgi` is not starting up?

**Update**

Below is the output of `docker ps -a` if its required. Note that `wsgi` container appears in the list below, but it was created 12 months back. Also its name has prefix `myapp_demo_fm_v2` and not `myapp_stack_2`. So its log of 12 months older run.

```
$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                      COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS                       PORTS     NAMES
589c3ded5c68   haproxy:2.3.9                              "docker-entrypoint.s…"   2 months ago    Exited (1) 2 months ago                myapp_stack_1_haproxy.1.ons0d6r68gcon872eg6wfx0nk
76cce6baa17a   myapp999/hello-world-node:v1             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 months ago    Exited (137) 4 months ago              jolly_thompson
946040fdb26d   myapp999/hello-world-node:v1             "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 months ago    Exited (137) 4 months ago              heuristic_wright
090eea4f6587   19b3b74cc027                               "/bin/sh -c /entrypo…"   12 months ago   Exited (1) 12 months ago               myapp_demo_fm_v2_wsgi.1.emfy78yn0lntyic4yxxtdqioy
dbdaa88dedc0   gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.30        "/usr/local/bin/entr…"   13 months ago   Exited (130) 2 months ago              minikube
876d7f293632   jenkins/jenkins:lts                        "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   13 months ago   Exited (143) 13 months ago             cranky_benz
dd88303738de   docker.elastic.co/beats/metricbeat:8.0.1   "/usr/bin/tini -- /u…"   14 months ago   Exited (0) 14 months ago               metricbeat2
430b061a9394   docker.elastic.co/beats/metricbeat:8.0.1   "/usr/bin/tini -- /u…"   14 months ago   Exited (1) 14 months ago               metricbeat
9d77b205edf8   vsc-volume-inspect                         "/bin/sh -c 'echo Co…"   15 months ago   Exited (0) 15 months ago               recursing_colden
```

Note that current `wsgi` container never appear in this list. I guess thats because `wsgi` container is not started at all when I run `docker stack deploy ...`, possibly some issue with `docker-compose` file. Two things I thought could be problematic:

- `wsgi` container may fail to start if `./wsgi/myapp` does not exist. But it does. I checked.
- Port `9090` is already occupied. But it is not. I checked with `sudo lsof -i :9090`.

Comment: Have you tried starting the three basic services (wsgi and redis/postgres it relies on) individually, ie without Docker compose?

Comment: Yess super thanks to point me out to this! I converted docker compose section of `wsgi` container to `docker run` command and ran it. It revealed that it was not able to find the image. I misspelled the image name in docker compose file as `wsgi:myapp3_stack2`. I missed single underscore: `wsgi:myapp3_stack_2`. Wish docker compose told me that !